# Skip invisible recaptcha images challenge

Tags: invisible-recaptcha

I'm trying to implement Invisible reCAPTCHA by Google. But after 5-6 times the images challenge comes up which is against the requirement . Is there a possibility of skipping the images challenge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I know of. The entire point of the invisible captcha is that it does not  show up when it is sure that the page is being visited by a human. If it is not sure or certain that it is a bot, the challange is presented.